# How to make apr available for subversion install?

Tags: software-installation, compiling, subversion, configure, apr

I try to install subversion from source, but on ./configure receive:

```
configure: error: no suitable apr found
```

I have download apr source and installed:

```
libraries have been installed in:
/usr/local/apr/lib
```

So I returned to configure of subversion but receive the same error.
What I should do? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When configuring Subversion, try

```
./configure --with-apr=/usr/local/apr/
```

That might not be exactly the right path.  Try finding `apr-config` and giving the path to that.  I'm guessing it might be:

```
./configure --with-apr=/usr/local/apr/bin/apr-config
```

Try `./configure --help` to see what your options are.  There are a lot of them.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried including the path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? I don't know how good an option this is, but something simple like this is worth a try:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}":/usr/local/apr/lib
```

Comment: THANK YOU. I upgraded my Mac to Big Sur a couple of days ago and have been trying to get `git-svn` working again ever since. It's been issue after issue, and this solved the last one for me!